# Visual Studio - What kind of project is this?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I try to emulate a Web Service Solution using Visual Studio, but i Realized this solution has 4 projects. A Web Aplication project and three projects, but i dont know what kind project is those  three projects (I mean, maybe application console o whatever)

https://i.ibb.co/fvBxbcR/asd.png
Please in this link you can see the SDK of these unknown projects for me, Someone knows what kind projects are?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to properly link the image. Use the image button on the toolbar to add it, instead of providing your own link elsewhere. The image must be stored in SO's imgur account so that it remains available for future readers here. We don't allow external links to the relevant content here. Thanks.

Comment: Simply the new SDK style projects, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/check-project-format

Answer (score 0):

The projects are .NET Core and are likely to be shared libraries used by your web application. If you aren't sure about any project, you can right click on the project (i.e. TaxiGreen.Common), select "Properties", and you should see some more information about the project.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a project, but a reference to the .NET Core Base classes, present in every .NET Core program. Note that other projects other than the highlighted one also have this very same node.

The "TaxiGreen.Common" looks like a C# .NET Core Class library, guessing based on the structure of the solution, but can't say for sure, as the icon isn't more descriptive than this.

Note that the "dependencies" item can be anything from another project in the solution, to an external library, a NuGet package or part of the .NET Framework or Core.

Answer (score 0):

Those 3 Project run for your IDE to compile your applicatio!  It's Type of gradle resources!  Hope you are clear know. If you Don't then search on YouTube you will be get a strong reference about it